# Displaying Image by File Name

Tags: android, imageview

I need to display an image by specifying the file name instead of by using resource. E.g `showImage("background.png")` instead of `showImage(R.drawable.background)`.

Any one knows how?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [Android Image Tutorial](http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/10934_3748281_1). There's an example that uses FileOutputStream to write an image, I'm sure there's FileInputStream, too. Here's [another code example](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-download-image-from-server-and.html) that downloads images and transforms them to an Inputstream that is decoded:

```
bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
imView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

> public static Bitmap decodeFile (String pathName, BitmapFactory.Options opts)

The options aren't mandatory, but in case you want to display large images you should provide them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to get the image using it's name from resource folder.

```
public int getImage(String imageName) {
    return this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
}
```